# JSON Not pulling data?

Tags: ios, json, cordova

Can anyone fill me in as to why this isn't pulling my JSON data. I think I have the syntax correct but the page doesn't pull the data. Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PhoneGap Ajax Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function appReady(){
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open("GET","http://www.lcbcchurch.com/mobileJSON/homeslideshow",true);
                ajax.send();

                ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0)){
                        eval('var data = ' + ajax.responseText + ';');
                        var theResults = data.results;
                        var theHTML = '';
                        for(var i=0;i<theResults.length;i++){
                            theHTML += [
                                        '<div class="avatar"> <img src='+theResults[i].slideshow-image+' />'].join('');
                        }
                        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = theHTML;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);

            </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it get executed? Did you try `alert` debugging?

Comment: Shouldn't you assign the onreadystatechange *before* you send()? [Or even before open()]

Comment: I'd recommend you **never** use `eval` on data you fetch dynamically, it's absolutely horrible from a security point of view! It's basically the hand-concatinating-SQL-queries of the JavaScript world...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without additional information, but:

Set ajax.onreadystatechange before you call .send() otherwise the response could, in theory, arrive before you've told the instance how to handle it - it would be entirely dependent on the browser implementation.

Secondly, are you hosting it, or trying it locally from your filesystem?  In many browsers, Ajax calls don't work from the filesystem (it is considered a cross site scripting vulnerability) - so its best to install a simple webserver locally to test on - and fetch the json from that too.

Lastly, don't use eval, its evil ;-)

Use

```
var result = JSON.parse(string);
```

instead.

Comment: A little more info for you. I am a novice as you can probably tell at all this. I'm using a tutorial and it works fine with a basic twitter query, "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bacon". However, when I plugin my url "http://www.lcbcchurch.com/mobileJSON/homeslideshow" and change the array calls it doesn't output anything. Could my json page not be right? I'm using an expression engine plugin to get the JSON info.